# Ionic get httpClient

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-httpclient

Return HttpClient is not good why ?

What Best Practice for use HttpClient ?

### Error Display (Login.ts)

[image: Error return]

### My code (Login.ts)

```
let body = new URLSearchParams();
  body.set('email', this.email);
  body.set('password', this.password);

 this.httpClient.post('https://example.com/user/auth', body.toString(), {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}})
 .map(res => res.json())
  .subscribe(
    data => {
      this.result = res;
    },
    err => {
      this.result = err;
      this.password = "";
    }
  );
```

### My configuration

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.5.0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.1

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : ios 4.5.5
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.3.1, (and 6 other plugins)

System:

   NodeJS : v10.14.1 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm    : 6.4.1
   OS     : macOS Mojave
```

Thank you

Comment: This is CORS issue. check your browser console logs

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you get that error without a proper status code (status: 0) that means the request failed to get a response. That can happen for many reasons like it failed to create a request connection or because of CORS policy.

To find out which one is the issue

1. Check console in google chrome or Firefox for a console.error message similar to URL 'has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.'
2. Mock the request using `curl` command in your terminal or use postman to see if the request fails.

---

By the way I see things you can change in your code.

1. in ionic-angular 3.9.2 it's no longer needed to parse `res.json()` with map. it's already parsed. So remove that.
2. in subscribe you have data as param name but you assigned this.results to **res**. It should be **data**.

---

```
this.httpClient.post('https://example.com/user/auth', body.toString(), {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8'}})
.subscribe((data) => {
  this.result = data;
}, (err) => {
  this.result = err;
  console.error(err);
  this.password = '';
});
```